# CRUD Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-layout, android-activity

I'm working on a mobile app on Android Studio for a university project. However, I'm not able to modify the table name in my CRUD, and if I do, it will cause the app to crash.

Here is my code:

AdminMathsActivity.java:

```
package com.example.schoolapp.Admin;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.schoolapp.R;

public class AdminMathsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DataBaseHelper2 peopleDB;

    Button btnAddData, btnViewData,btnUpdateData,btnDelete;
    EditText etName,etEmail,etTVShow,etID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_maths);

        peopleDB = new DataBaseHelper2(this);

        etID = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etID);
        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewEmail);
        etTVShow = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewTVShow);
        btnAddData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddData);
        btnViewData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnViewData);
        btnUpdateData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUpdateData);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        AddData();
        ViewData();
        UpdateData();
        DeleteData();
    }

    public void AddData() {
        btnAddData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name = etName.getText().toString();
                String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                String tvShow = etTVShow.getText().toString();

                boolean insertData = peopleDB.addData(name, email, tvShow);

                if (insertData == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Vos données ont bien été insérez!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Vos données n’ont pas été insérez, veuillez réessayer.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void ViewData(){
        btnViewData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor data = peopleDB.showData();

                if (data.getCount() == 0) {
                    display("Erreur", "Aucune données n'a été insérez.");
                    return;
                }
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (data.moveToNext()) {
                    buffer.append("ID Note: " + data.getString(0) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("ID Eleve: " + data.getString(1) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Intitule: " + data.getString(2) + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Note: " + data.getString(3) + "\n");

                    display("Toutes les données insérez :", buffer.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void display(String title, String message){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

    public void UpdateData(){
        btnUpdateData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int temp = etID.getText().toString().length();
                if (temp > 0) {
                    boolean update = peopleDB.updateData(etID.getText().toString(), etName.getText().toString(),
                            etEmail.getText().toString(), etTVShow.getText().toString());
                    if (update == true) {
                        Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Vos données ont bien été modifiés!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Vos données n’ont pas été modifiés, veuillez réessayer.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Veuillez entrer un ID pour effectuer une modification!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void DeleteData(){
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int temp = etID.getText().toString().length();
                if(temp > 0){
                    Integer deleteRow = peopleDB.deleteData(etID.getText().toString());
                    if(deleteRow > 0){
                        Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Vos données ont bien été supprimé!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Vos données n’ont pas été supprimé, veuillez réessayer.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(AdminMathsActivity.this, "Veuillez entrer un ID pour effectuer une suppression!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

DataBaseHelper2.java code:

```
package com.example.schoolapp.Admin;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "people.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
    public static final String COL1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL3 = "EMAIL";
    public static final String COL4 = "TVSHOW";


    public DataBaseHelper2(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                " NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, TVSHOW TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(createTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String name, String email, String tvShow){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL4, tvShow);

        long result  = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);

        if(result == -1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }

    public Cursor showData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        return data;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id, String name, String email, String tvShow){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL1,id);
        contentValues.put(COL2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL3,email);
        contentValues.put(COL4,tvShow);
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteData(String id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?", new String[] {id});
    }

}
```

activity_admin_maths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Admin.AdminMathsActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="ID :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etID"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnUpdateData"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnUpdateData"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:hint="Utilisation pour modifier et supprimer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="ID de l'eleve"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etID" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNewName"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Intitule"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNewName" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNewEmail"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Note"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNewEmail" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etNewTVShow"
        android:layout_width="391dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView5" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Ajouter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNewTVShow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnViewData"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnAddData"
        android:text="Visualiser"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etNewTVShow" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnUpdateData"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etNewEmail"
        android:layout_marginStart="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="64dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/btnViewData"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnViewData"
        android:text="Modifier"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAddData" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="64dp"
        android:text="Supprimer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnViewData" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is the error log :

```
 2019-03-01 15:41:51.277 10663-10663/com.example.schoolapp E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: people_table2
    2019-03-01 15:41:51.282 10663-10663/com.example.schoolapp E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting EMAIL=Fonction TVSHOW=15/20 NAME=1
        android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: people_table2 (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: INSERT INTO people_table2(EMAIL,TVSHOW,NAME) VALUES (?,?,?)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1562)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1433)
            at com.example.schoolapp.Admin.DataBaseHelper2.addData(DataBaseHelper2.java:43)
            at com.example.schoolapp.Admin.AdminMathsActivity$1.onClick(AdminMathsActivity.java:52)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
            at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
            at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Basically if I change the table name to people_table2 for example, data won't be inserted in SQLite.

Comment: you want to modify the table name? if wont let you? it crashes? I think the crash log would be pretty helpful here...also the "issue" you face has nothing to do with android-layout or android-activity

Comment: please share the error log

Comment: @JinsLukose i've updated the original post with the error log.

Comment: @AlexandreDeCoriolis the error is because the table is not created . please clear the data and try .otherwise check the table exist in device explorer in android studio

Comment: Please update your sql version name 1 to 2 `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would not modify a table name, that is unless you were modifying the structure and eventually renaming the renamed table back to it's original name.

However, you can use [ALTER TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) to rename a table. However, note that in doing so you would have to modify the App accordingly so that the changed table name is used throughout.

If you just want to change the table name used when the table is first created (*simply change `public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";` to `public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table2";`*), i.e. in the **onCreate** method, but after the App has been previously run using the older table name. Then the simplest way is to :-

1. Make the code changes,
2. Do 1 of the following

   1. delete/clear the App's data or
   2. uninstall the App
   3. or in your case increase the database version (e.g. change `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`)
3. rerun the App.

   - *Note that doing 2.1 or 2.2 above will lose any data that has been stored in the database. To preserve data is possible but is more complex.* Using 2.3 will result in a new table being created with the old one remaining.

The reason is that the **onCreate** method only runs when the database itself is created.

## Additional

As the syntax for the DROP TABLE statement is wrong. If you change the table name AND increase the version then the App will crash with an error like :-

```
2019-03-01 16:25:12.956 5963-5963/aaa.adminmaths E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: aaa.adminmaths, PID: 5963
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "IF": syntax error (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: DROP IF TABLE EXISTS people_table
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:903)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:514)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1769)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1698)
        at aaa.adminmaths.DataBaseHelper2.onUpgrade(DataBaseHelper2.java:33)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:398)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:298)
        at aaa.adminmaths.DataBaseHelper2.showData(DataBaseHelper2.java:54)
        at aaa.adminmaths.AdminMathsActivity$2.onClick(AdminMathsActivity.java:65)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

That is because the syntax should be `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS the_table_name_to_drop`

Comment: That's what i've tried to do. As soon as i change (public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";)  to  (public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table2";) the insertion won't work. But if i keep (public static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";) it's working fine.

Comment: @AlexandreDeCoriolis If you tried changing the version number and thus utilising **onUpgrade**, then **onUpgrade** will fail because you have `DROP IF TABLE EXISTS` instead of `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`. The answer includes this finding. Copying the code above then appears to work fine (noting that I do not understand whatever language is used.)